# AutoMapper Profile for composite entity mapping

Tags: c#, automapper, blazor-server-side

I have a profile setup like so:

```
public class DomainToViewModelProfile : Profile
{
    public DomainToViewModelProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<DataPrivacy, DataPrivacyViewModel>();
        CreateMap<DeliveryStage, DeliveryStageViewModel>();
        CreateMap<FundedState, FundedStateViewModel>();
        CreateMap<Gate, GateViewModel>();
        CreateMap<Location, LocationViewModel>();
        CreateMap<PersonRole, PersonRoleViewModel>();
        CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>();
        CreateMap<ProjectGate, ProjectGateViewModel>();
        CreateMap<ProjectStatus, ProjectStatusViewModel>();

        CreateMap<RadarProject, RadarProjectViewModel>();
        CreateMap<ManualData, ManualDataViewModel>();
    }
}
```

I, now, have a new model to map nut it is just a class with two properties that are the last two mappings above:

```
public class DesignProjectViewModel
{
    public DesignProjectViewModel()
    {

    }

    public DesignProjectViewModel(RadarProjectViewModel radar, ManualDataViewModel manual)
    {
        RadarProject      = radar;
        ManualDataProject = manual;
    }

    public DesignProjectViewModel(DesignProjectViewModel model)
    {
        RadarProject = model.RadarProject;
        ManualDataProject = model.ManualDataProject;
    }

    public RadarProjectViewModel RadarProject      { get; set; }
    public ManualDataViewModel   ManualDataProject { get; set; }
}
```

How do I create a map for this class?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html

Comment: I also realized that this would be possible the other way around. I might have to rethink this bit.